# BindingResult populates the error message in eclipse console but not in form/ webpage

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

```js
@RequestMapping(value="/saveOrUpdate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getSaved(@Valid Users users,BindingResult result){
  Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
  
  userServices.saveOrUpdate(users);
   if(result.hasErrors())
   {
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("users");
    return model;
   }
   else
   {
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("users"); 
    return model;
   }}
```

> Have i made any mistake, or is it wrong to use bindingresult with responsebody annotation, could anyone please advice me how to get this fixed.
>   just to clarify all validation annotation @size @pattern etc are working fine they do the validation and persist only valid data but the problem is when user gives inaccurate values the error is reflected in console why its data is not persisted but not in form

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `<form:errors ..... />` below is the sample to display userName field error

`<form:errors path="useraName" class="form-control-feedback" />`

Comment: thats cool Kathirvel but im not using spring form tag im just using normal html tag and passing the form user values via jquery and catching in controller via responsebody annotation not modelattribute annotation, could you tell me how to achieve this using normal html tags

Answer (score 0):

> After hours of effort i finally found a way to bindthe error response message of bindingresult object in to map as key value and send it to json handler function

for those trying to implement spring mvc form handling with html tags instead of spring form tags and trying to get the values of error message to populate and display in your webpage for a similar code like above follow the below snippet:

@RequestMapping(value="/saveOrUpdate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody  Map getSaved(@Valid Users users,BindingResult result){
        Map map = new HashMap();

```
    Object obj=new Object();
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {  
            for (Object object : result.getAllErrors()) {
                if(object instanceof FieldError) {
                    FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

                 obj= (fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
                }
            map.put("status","400");
            map.put("message",obj);
            return map;
        }}
           userServices.saveOrUpdate(users);
        map.put("status","200");
        map.put("message","Your record have been saved successfully");
        return map;
        }
```